# Testing in-app purchases in Kindle Fire application

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, kindle-fire

I am not able to test in app purchases even with Amazon Appstore SDK Tester.

```
public void onPurchaseResponse(final PurchaseResponse purchaseResponse)
```

purchaseResponse always has "INVALID_SKU" even if I have amazon.sdktester.json file with fake JSON.

file content:
    {
    "test" : {
        "itemType": "CONSUMABLE",
        "price": 0.99,
        "title": "More Clicks!",
        "description": "Click your button ten more times!",
        "smallIconUrl": "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
      },

```
"com.amazon.buttonclicker.ten_clicks" : {
    "itemType": "CONSUMABLE",
    "price": 0.99,
    "title": "More Clicks!",
    "description": "Click your button ten more times!",
    "smallIconUrl": "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
  },

  "com.amazon.buttonclicker.blue_button" : {
    "itemType": "ENTITLED",
    "price": 0.99,
    "title": "Blue Button",
    "description": "Button Clicker - Now in Blue!",
    "smallIconUrl": "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
  }
}
```

Even sample application does not work.
Do you have any suggestions how to test application? It seems that Amazon SDK Tester does not intercept requests.

Comment: Newbie Question: Did you have to register the sample app and the IAP Items with their SKU's in the Amazon Developer Portal before you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like magic but hard reset resolved all my problems.

Comment: Same Here : 

I was able to test consumable and subscription, but not able to reset everything with App Tester to start from scratch.

Force Close + Clear Data -> fix it !

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I got the In App purchases to work on Kindle Fire (after several hrs of struggle...)

1. adb install AmazonSDKTester.apk (Install SDKTester on Kindle Fire)
2. Create a file amazon.sdktester.json in the SDCARD directory (The connected KF shows up as SDCARD in Finder on ur Mac)
3. Contents of amazon.sdktester.json - **{
   "com.yourcompany.yourpkgname.200_coins" : {
   "itemType": "CONSUMABLE",
   "price": 0.99,
   "title": "200 COINS",
   "description": "2 COINS",
   "smallIconUrl": "http://www.yourcompany.com/icon.png"
   }
   }**
4. Press the power button on KF & press "Disconnect" button - Now KF is no longer a mounted drive on ur Mac.
5. Run the AmazonSDKTester app on KF.
6. Run your app from Eclipse. Make sure the package name in the JSON matches the In App Item SKU on Amazon's website & in the **PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest("com.yourcompany.yourpkgname.200_coins");**
7. Now you should see the In App interstitials showing up.
8. Still doesn't work - Force Close both your app & AmazonSDKTester on KF; Hard Reset KF ; Restart Eclipse & Restart from Step 1

Comment: how can i detect that whether app is already purchased or not, just like queryinventory in play store

Comment: Also worth to mention that IAP v2 works only with AmazonSDKTester distributed via amazon store. It took me a while to find it out. Thanks to this link: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=3735 (under Known Issues and Helpful Notes v2). Though the documentation looks inconsistent and fragmented to me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the outer enclosing {} braces in your json.
It took me 3 hours until I figured that out...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to hit the disconnect button after you connect the usb cable to your pc, otherewise the SDK tester will not be able to read the JSON file you moved over since the device is mounted at that point.  Found this out the hard way.

Comment: I had trouble with this too, if I remember correctly I moved the JSON file over, force closed the SDK tester, re-opened it, then tested my app.  It did seem a bit wonky I remember.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the issue that the same as your, the key is: in your java code, your item id must equal to your SKU in json file, in this case, it must be: `com.amazon.buttonclicker.ten_clicks` or `com.amazon.buttonclicker.blue_button`
Here is the example json file for `SampleIAPConsumablesApp` and `SampleIAPEntitlementsApp` sample project provied by Amazon:

```
{
"com.amazon.sample.iap.consumable.orange" : {

    "itemType": "CONSUMABLE",

    "price": 0.99,

    "title": "More Clicks!",

    "description": "Click your button ten more times!",

    "smallIconUrl": "http://some/image.jpg"

  },

  "com.amazon.sample.iap.entitlement.level2" : {

    "itemType": "ENTITLED",

    "price": 0.99,

    "title": "Blue Button",

    "description": "Button Clicker - Now in Blue!",

    "smallIconUrl": "http://some/image.jpg"

  }
}
```

Goodluck!